# How do I change the color of all of the materialize .btn, .btn-large, and .btn-small to .pink,.accent-1?

Tags: sass, materialize, css-specificity

I tried to do

```
    .btn, .btn-large, .btn-small{
        @extend .pink, .accent-1
     }
```

Is there an issue with the specificity?

Answer (score 1):

You can just override the default **btn** class by changing **background-color** property like:

```
.btn {
   background-color: red;
   color: white;
}
```

Button would be like

```
<button class="btn btn-lg">Hello</button>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're only looking for an answer in SASS, but here's a solution in pure CSS.

From the [Materialize.css docs](https://materializecss.com/color.html) get the hex colour code for pink-accent-1 `#ff80ab` and apply `!important` parameter to the `background-colour` for the buttons just to be sure to override the default Materialize classes.

```
.btn , .btn-small, .btn-large{
    background-color: #ff80ab !important;
}
```

Here's a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kcamcam/pmv65erk/37/).

Comment: I should clarify. The `styles.scss` file (compiled into styles.min.scss) reads 

```@import "components/_color-variables.scss";
@import "components/_color-classes.scss";
nav .nav-wrapper{
  @extend .pink;
}
.btn, .btn-large, .btn-small{
  background-color: #ff80ab !important;
}```, and the buttons aren't working but the navbars are.

Comment: Have you recompiled the scss file? I just ran the code you provided locally and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Oh! It seems like I misplaced my styles.min.css file. Sorry, everyone. It's really nice to know I have these kinds of resources if I need them.